# How to perform Hierarchical Clustering using centroid method and custom distance metric?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering, scipy, distance-functions

I would like to perform Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering using the centroid method (defined on [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) page) and a custom distance metric, probably cosine similarity. In the Scipy docs it says you must use Euclidean distances if you want to use the centroid method.

Is there a simple way to pre-process my data so that Euclidean distances are effectively calculating a different distance (e.g. preprocess so the Euclidean distances would derive a cosine similarity distance)?

Or else, is there a way for me to easily amend the SciPy Code to make its algorithm work for non-euclidean distances?

I looked through the SciPy code and found the function that updates distances to new clusters (see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.4/scipy/cluster/_hierarchy_distance_update.pxi)) and it appears to use some smart maths to calculate new distances using just the distances between the old clusters and number of items in each cluster. I don't know how to derive this calculation for cosine similarity.